# How to add a line of best fit, equation, R^2, and p-value to a plot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph

I have the df1:

```
   Stabr  PCTPOVALL_2018 FIPS score1 score2    score3
3     AL  13.8          1001    26      3         10
4     AL  9.8           1003    20      1         5
7     AL  13.2          1009    21      6         7
8     AL  42.5          1011    60      5         10
9     AL  24.5          1013    65      3         10
10    AL  19.5          1015    42      2         8
```

I would like to plot `df1$PCTPOVALL_2018` against `score1`. I would also like to run a linear regression to see if there is a significant association between these variables. I would then like to plot the p-value, the R^2, and the line of best fit onto this graph. I have included an image that I made in paint for reference. I know to begin with `plot(df1$PCTPOVALL_2018,df1$score1,xlab="Pov",ylab="Score",main"Score vs Pov")`[image]

how do I add these components? Do I need to use ggplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `abline` to draw the line according to the slope and intercept of the adjusted linear model and use `text` to add the additional information to the plot (using `paste` to convert all the information to a string).

```
#Save summary of the linear model
sum_lm<-summary(lm(score1~PCTPOVALL_2018, data = df1))

#Get coefficients
coef_lm<-sum_lm$coefficients

#Plot
plot(df1$PCTPOVALL_2018,
     df1$score1,
     xlab="Pov",
     ylab="Score",
     main= "Score vs Pov")

#Set the abline as the coefficients obtained by your linear model
abline(a = coef_lm[1,1], 
       b = coef_lm[2,1], 
       col = "lightblue",
       lwd = 2)

#Add text to the plot in the x and y position (you might need to adjust these values according to your data)
#and add as labels a string that pastes all the info you wish to include. \n is interpreted as a line break. 
text(x = max(df1$PCTPOVALL_2018)-20, 
     y = min(df1$score1)+10, 
     labels = paste0("R^2 = ",
                     #Round r.squared to 2 decimals
                     round(sum_lm$r.squared,2),
                     "\np-value = ",
                     #Round p.value of slope to 2 decimals
                     round(coef_lm[2,4],2),
                     "\ny = ", 
                     #Round slope coefficient to 2 decimals
                     round(coef_lm[2,1],1),
                     "x + ", 
                     #Round intercept coefficient to 2 decimals
                     round(coef_lm[1,1],2)),
     pos = 4)
```

Here is the resulting plot with your data.

[image: linear regression plot]

Comment: This is great, is there any way to be more specific with placement of text than positions 1,2,3, or 4?

Comment: Yeah, actually the `x`and `y` inside the `text` function set the coordinates where you want to draw the text, while `pos` only affects the position of the text according to the specified coordinates. For example, `pos = 4` draws the text to the right of the these  coordinates.

Comment: You could set `pch` and `col` arguments inside the `plot` function to change the default color and shapes of data points.